# Skrill(Moneybookers) return data and HTTPS

Tags: php, https, payment-gateway, payment

Right so i am using Skrill or MOneybookers as it used to be known for payments on my website. The problem is that when it posts data back to my server i can't seem to collect anything. I'm looking for $_POST['status'] value but it isn't there.

I've tried a number of different things and nothing has worked. So i got an idea, i am using .htaccess to force users onto the website to use https, could this be generating the problem, because skrill is posting this data back to lets say http://www.mysite.com/skrillReturn.php and its forcing it to https could it be blocking the posted data?

I am sort of new to a lot of this so i was wondering if this could be problematic for me? and if so is there a way to change this without losing HTTPS?

Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We allways use a different virtual host for payment provider postbacks, isolation creates robustness. On this second virtual host, don't do any redirect tricks etc.

Comment: Just test it without https and it works... Is there a way to exclude a page from the redirect?

Comment: Sure there is, but please keep in mind that using the same vhost for app and postback is inherently dangerous, if anybody in the app team doesn't know/care/think of side effects for postback when working with the user-visible part of teh app.