# Can't access the $_POST variables from Skrill

Tags: php, integration, payment-gateway, payment

I am trying to integrate Skrill payment gateway to my website. But after a successful payment, I can't access the skrill $_POST variables from my status_url.
And hence, i can't capture the user details from my site.

```
  <form action='https://www.moneybookers.com/app/payment.pl' METHOD='POST'><p class="text-center"> 
                         <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.10">

                        <input type="hidden" name="pay_to_email" value="mygmail@gmail.com"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="status_url" value="http://website.com/pages/verify.php"/> 
                         <input type="hidden" name="status_url2" value="mygmail@gmail.com"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="http://website.com/pages/marketplace.php"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="language" value="EN"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amounttopay" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="USD"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="detail1_description" value="my desc"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="detail1_text" value="Buy product"/>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block" value="Pay!"/>
```

But i can't access the Skrill variables in verify.php

```
 <?php
    $MBEmail = "mygmail@gmail.com";
    //This if statement is not working since there is no $_POST variables from skrill.
    if ($_POST['status'] == 2 && $_POST['pay_to_email'] == $MBEmail) 
    {
        // Valid transaction.
         //update the database.
    }
    else
    {
        // Invalid transaction. Bail out
        exit;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: It is already better to look for a string value of 2: change `$_POST['status'] == 2 ` to `$_POST['status'] == '2' `. If you do a `print_r($_POST)`, in verify.php, what do you see then?

Comment: I can't print out the variables since skrill is posting to the verify.php page and redirect to the return_url after posting, i think.

Comment: Found a similar thread. But didn't got answer. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688704/skrillmoneybookers-return-data-and-https?rq=1

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

to capture the returned status from the gateway, you need to mention proper the return url below,i.e on your website

```
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="http://website.com/pages/marketplace.php"/>
```

try to check the documentation at,

```
https://www.skrill.com/fileadmin/templates/main/res/material/documents/pdf/getting-started/skrill-integration-manual-en.pdf
```

Comment: But, i think its not the returned_url that i want to use to get the payment details. i think its the status_url. isn't it?

Comment: yes it is status_url, and status_url2 URL to which the transaction details are posted after the payment process is complete. The return url is the place or file you can capture the status_url on your website.

Comment: i don't really understood. So i do want to listen for the variables in the return_url instead of status_url?

Comment: I tried print_r($_POST) in the return_url. But its empty.

Comment: the return_url should be a url in your website not something junk

Comment: yes. its a url in my site. But the $_POST variables in the url is empty

Comment: anyone knows a solution?

Comment: @Nisthar Did you get the solution for an issue?